# JCrop and the iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, jquery-plugins, jcrop

I have a nice little app using [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) and now its broken on the iPad and iPhone. Has anyone any experience getting jCrop working on a touch device and if so any help/samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check out the new version of Jcrop, it has experimental touch support. Works for me on the iPad/Android/etc.